# How to check whether a file exists at user defined path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am having a file called demo.png which is saved in the `documents/test/` folder. 
Now I want to check whether the files exists at that particular path and I want to delete that file. How to check that can you please tell me ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 


 NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo.html"];
 BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];


 if (fileExists)    //Does file exist?
     {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])   //Delete it
    {
        NSLog(@"Delete file error: %@", error);
    }
   }
```

Comment: what is the URL for path here ?

Answer (score 5):

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:somePath])
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:somePath error:NULL];
```

This can be used to check if file exist at your path.